# AngularJS, Two level menu add "active" class to both the active sub-item and its parent based on url

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

If it's just one level navigation/menu, url like "localhost/#/user"

**I know I can use**:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/user')}><a href="#/user'>User</a></li>
</ul>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.isActive = function (path) {
  if ( path == $location.path() )
    return true;
  return false;
};
```

then when url is "localhost/#/user", "active" will be added.

**Yet when it comes to two level menu**, url like "localhost/#/user/orders"

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#/user'>User</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/user/orders'>Orders</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>   
</ul>
```

**How can I add "active" class to both the item "orders" and its parent "user" based on url?**  ( so I can highlight them both )

Thanks in advance.

---

Update:

### Thanks, it's working now :D

@Nikos Paraskevopoulos, @piatek, @Chandermani **thanks**

**here's my final working code written in CoffeeScript**, though the code is not good enough, but it works :)

```
.directive('highlightActive', () ->
    return {
        restrict: "A"
        controller: [
            '$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$location'
            ($scope, $element, $attrs, $location) ->
                links = $element.find('a')
                path = () ->
                    return $location.path()

                highlightActive = (links, path) ->
                    path = '#' + path

                    angular.forEach(links, (link) ->
                        $link = angular.element(link)
                        $li = $link.parent('li')
                        href = $link.attr('href')

                        if ($li.hasClass('active'))
                            $li.removeClass('active')
                        if path.indexOf(href) is 0
                            $li.addClass('active')
                    )

                highlightActive(links, $location.path())

                $scope.$watch(path, (newVal, oldVal) ->
                    if newVal is oldVal
                        return
                    highlightActive(links, $location.path())
                )
        ]

    }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your URLs follow the hierarchy of the menus (i.e. `/user` → `/user/orders` → `/user/orders/something`, where → means submenu), you could check string containment with a simple directive:

```
app.directive("menuHref", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<li><a ng-href='{{ href }}'>{{ text }}</a></li>",
        scope: {
            text: "="
        },
        controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs", "$location", function($scope, $element, $attrs, $location) {
            $scope.href = "#" + $attrs.menuHref;

            $scope.$watch(
                function() {
                    return $location.hash().startsWith($attrs.menuHref);
                },
                function(newval) {
                    $element.toggleClass("active", newval);
                }
            );
        }]
    };
});
```

Use it as:

```
<li menu-href="/user/orders" text="Orders"></li>
```

(note href does not start with `#`, the `<a>` is generated by the directive)

I haven't tested this code, it may contain small bugs (we can discuss them) but I think the principle should work.

Comment: nice, but why setup the $watch in the controller and not in the linking function? what is the benefit?

Comment: @piatek I need to access the `$location` service, thus I need the controller because it can specify dependencies. Therefore I put the entire logic in the controller, so as to keep it in one place.

Answer (score 2):

One way i can think of, would be to pass multiple arguments to `isActive` such as

```
<li ng-class="{active: isActive(['/user','/user/orders'])}><a href="#/user'>User</a></li>
```

and then check match to any one of the paths.

Comment: Thanks :) It should work, yet if a list has many sub lists, say 6, then the array will be really long :P

Comment: Agreed and I understand that. Will update the answer if i can think of something else :)

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of ways to do this, I would just add a directive on the top element as angular tends to beef up the HTML anyway.

```
<ul activeli>
  <li>
    <a href="#/users">User</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#/users/orders/">Orders</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/users/account/">Account</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

App.directive('activeli', function ($location) {
  return function ($scope, $el) {
    var links = $el.find('a'),
        path = function(){ return $location.path(); }

    function addActiveClass (links, path) {
        angular.forEach(links, function (link) {
            var $link = angular.element(link);

            if ($link.hasClass('active')) {
                $link.removeClass('active');
            } else if (link.hash === ('#' + path)) {
                $link.addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }

    // Initial state
    addActiveClass(links, $location.path());

    $scope.$watch(path, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue === oldValue) return;
        addActiveClass(links, $location.path());
    });
  };

});
```